# Java create XML output file

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have a task:

"The task is to output an XML file with all counted results. It would be great if an XSL file for viewing the produced XML nicely using a web browser is also provided. "

The counted results looks like:

```
Feta Sushi;12.61;5.00;9.22;1.50;60.39;16.43;21.60;2.60;35.81;5.25.72 
Siemak Beata;13.04;4.53;7.79;1.55;64.72;18.74;24.20;2.40;28.20;6.50.76 
Hodson Wind;13.75;4.84;10.12;1.50;68.44;19.18;30.85;2.80;33.88;6.22.75 
Seper Loop;13.43;4.35;8.64;1.50;66.06;19.05;24.89;2.20;33.48;6.51.01
```

I don't know how to output data from Java application to the XML file. Also how the XSL file should be produced?

Would be great if someone find time to show me how to do this.

Comment: You could start by taking a read through [Java API for XML Processing (JAXP)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/)

Comment: Create Java object. use JAXB to generate XML from java object. Write aan  xsl file display the XML in desired format

Answer (score 0):

```
        /*
         * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
         * and open the template in the editor.
         */
        package com.rest.client;

        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.List;
        import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
        import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
        import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

        /**
         *
         * @author sxalam
         */
        @XmlRootElement(name = "tasks")
        public class Task {

            String name;

            List<Double> task;

            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }

            public void setName(String name) {
                this.name = name;
            }

            public List<Double> getTask() {
                return task;
            }

            public void setTask(List<Double> task) {
                this.task = task;
            }


        }
```

Use following class to generate XML from java objects

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

public class JAXBJavaToXml {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // creating country object
    Task task = new Task();        
    task.setName("Feta Sushi");

    List<Double> counter = new ArrayList<Double>();
    counter.add(12.5);
    counter.add(10.90);

    task.setTask(counter);
    try {

        // create JAXB context and initializing Marshaller
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Task.class);
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

        // for getting nice formatted output
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);

        //specify the location and name of xml file to be created
        File XMLfile = new File("C:\\task.xml");

        // Writing to XML file
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(task, XMLfile);
        // Writing to console
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(task, System.out);            

    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        // some exception occured
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}